# Some Pictures don't shown using primefaces-5.0.jar

Tags: primefaces

I created a web project and I'm using primefaces-5.0.jar
I would like to integrate the option ***Multimedia > Galleria***.
Everything seems well, but I couldn't show the pictures (only using **Multimedia**, the pictures within other options are shown without any problem).
I don't know what's missing ?!

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning Galleria or even other options inside Multimedia, we should make different pictures while we are talking there about a list of pictures !.